# USB-C docking station can't keep image up - keeps kicking me out to Windows lock screen

Tags: windows-10, usb-c, thunderbolt

New Lenovo Win10 laptop set up with lenovo docking station (thunderbolt 3 gen 2) and display port cable to external monitor.

Problem is after a few seconds computer kicks me out to Windows lock screen.

Using same laptop with Anker usb-c hub and different monitor at second location but get same results.

Laptop on its' own is fine and no dedicated video output so I have to start with usb-c.

Tried updating everything, drivers, settings, etc. but can't figure this out.

Anyone got any good ideas?

Comment: What model is the laptop, what is the Windows 10 version, and are your BIOS and drivers up to date?

Comment: Lenovo carbon x1 - 20UN005JUS - just a few months old.  All Windows and Lenovo updates, including BIOS, are done.  I'm not currently with machine so i can't give you exact windows version.

Comment: Questions: (1) If you unlock, does it happen again? (2) Does it also happen when booting in Safe mode? (3) Does it happen if you use a self-powered dock (if you have one)? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: 1) yes, it will happen again and again.  2) don't know.  3)using self powered lenovo dock and in separate location using an Anker bus powered usb-c dock with same results.

Comment: 2) Try [booting in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234).

Comment: OK.  I'll try that tomorrow.  If it works fine in safe mode then the fix is to create a new user and use that instead?

Comment: The usual explanation in that case is that it's caused by some installed startup app. Its working in a new user account means that the installed app was per-user.

Answer (score 0):

screen close sensor is at the bottom right of the touch pad. a magnet will set it off. make sure you aren't wearing a magnetic bracelet or watch band.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You could improve your answer for example, by linking to a website where it talks about the location of the sensor.